# Passing JSON string list malforms strings?

Tags: c#

I'm saving a list of strings to my backend api but its malforming the string somehow. I have checked all possible things but I have had no sleep for 48 hours so I'm probably missing it.

It seems to replace _ with amp - not sure.

Correct string (also the string before persisting)

```
&_nc_cat=100&oh=2709db2b099e5eb5bb6eb19654de828a&oe=5E7FF7C5
```

The string after persisting

```
&amp;_nc_cat=100&amp;oh=2cda55a0255b0ef3afabe535412a43f8&amp;oe=5E7FF7C5
```

The full orignal correct string is actually
https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/s640x640/75448871_111514890143520_4913259559873269659_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&oh=2709db2b099e5eb5bb6eb19654de828a&oe=5E7FF7C5

Here is how I save to my api

```
var response = HttpFactory.PushItemToCache(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "item", Url },
    { "username", Username },
    { "name", Name },
    { "picture", Picture },
    { "pictures", Pictures },
});
```

Http Methods:

```
public static IRestResponse PushItemToCache(Dictionary<string, object> data)    
{
    return HttpUtilities.Post("/api/cache", data);
}
```

Post method:

```
public static IRestResponse PerformResource(string resource, IDictionary<string, object> data = default, string method = "GET", bool checkToken = true)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var request = new RestRequest(resource);

    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {_bearerToken}");

    if (data == null)
    {
        data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    data.Add("owner", Environment.UserName + Environment.MachineName);

    if (method != "GET")
    {
        request.AddJsonBody(data);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var pair in data)
        {
            request.AddParameter(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    IRestResponse response;

    switch (method)
    {
        case "POST":
            response = RestClient.Post(request);
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            response = RestClient.Delete(request);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            response = RestClient.Delete(request);
            break;
        case "PATCH":
            response = RestClient.Patch(request);
            break;
        default:
            response = RestClient.Get(request);
            break;
    }

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        new ConsoleLogger().Error("Response for " + resource + " returned " + response.StatusDescription);
        new ConsoleLogger().Error(response.Content);
        new ConsoleLogger().Error(response.ErrorMessage);
    }

    if (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 5)
    {
        new ConsoleLogger().Pink($"This request ({resource}) took {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds");
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your string is url encoded, you can convert it back using [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=netframework-4.8)

[working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9F7037)